# Python - Load Image in Label

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

Im having a hard time loading an image in a label using [PAGE GUI Generator](http://page.sourceforge.net/). Below is my UI:

[image]

Everytime I click the "Browse Document" button, it calls an `open_file_dialog_function`, below is the function:

```
def open_file_dialog(self):

   self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select A File", filetype =  (("jpeg", "*.jpg"), ("All Files", "*.*")))

   #Display Document Path
   self.label_document_path1 = ttk.Label(self.label_document_path, text = "")
   self.label_document_path1.grid(column = 1, row = 2)         
   self.label_document_path1.configure(text = self.filename)

   #Load Damaged Document
   load = Image.open(self.filename)
   render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load) 

   self.label_input_document1 = ttk.Label(self.label_input_document, image = render)
   self.label_input_document1.grid(column = 1, row = 3)  
   self.label_input_document1.configure(image = render)
```

Everytime the function is performed, it only shows white in the supposed image. Why is it? Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Try `self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)` instead?

Comment: @HenryYik -- tried but nothing happened :( The image does not load and the white background also disappears.